# Time ordering and Fermions

Tags: time, operators, fermions, second-quantization

Having time ordering operator for fermions, should it reverse sign if it swaps operators with opposite spin variable? In other words should 
$T[c_{t_1,\uparrow}c_{t_2,\downarrow}^\dagger]$ 
return $T[c_{t_2,\downarrow}^\dagger c_{t_1,\uparrow}]$ or $-T[c_{t_2,\downarrow}^\dagger c_{t_1,\uparrow}]$ if $t_2 > t_1$?

Comment: It should. For any pair of fermionic variables it is natural to consider their anticommutator (I guess it is possible in some cases to build a theory with *different* fermionic fields that commute with each other, like take a tensor product of any two theories, but its ugly), the only problem is whether it is zero or not. $T$ assumes it to be zero. You should look at the definitions and motivations in order to understand why it is so.

Comment: See also [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Path-ordering).