# Propagator Causality with commutators all the way

Tags: quantum-field-theory, commutator, causality

We know that two fields commute - by locality and causality - *iff* there is spacelike separation

$\left[\phi_l^k(x) , \phi_m^{k'}(y)\right] = 0$ for $(x-y)^2<0$

In the canonical quantization of the Dirac field, if $b_\alpha(k)$ is the annihilation operator and  $b^\dagger_\alpha(k)$ is the creation operator for a particle of 4-momentum $k$  with

$\left[b_\alpha(k), b^\dagger_\beta(q)\right] = (2\pi)^3\frac{\omega_\mathbf k}{m} \delta^{(3)}(\mathbf{k}-\mathbf{q})\delta_{\alpha\beta}$

and $\psi^{(+)}(x) = e ^{-ikx}u(k) $ is a solution with positive energy while  $\psi^{(-)}$ is negative, when we use commutators all the way, the following

$\left[\psi_\xi(x) , \overline\psi_\eta(y)\right] = (i\not\partial_x+m)\int{\frac{d^3k}{(2\pi)^3}\frac{1}{2\omega_\mathbf k}\left[e^{-ik(x-y)} + e^{+ik(x-y)}\right]|_{k=(\omega_k,\mathbf k )}}$

does not vanish for spacelike separations and results in a violation of causality. How is this problem overcome or why isn't it a problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've noted in comments that:

- If you write fermions $f_1,\,f_2$ as $f_i=\eta_ic_i$ with $\{\eta_i,\,\eta_j\}=[\eta_i,\,c_j]=0$, $\{f_1,\,f_2\}=\eta_1\eta_2[c_1,\,c_2]$;
- This works whether these objects are operators or not, but if they are operators, all matrix elements will be complex;
- The operators in question will have uncountable dimension.

Let's also discuss what happens when you make a boson out of two fermions (if you use a larger even number of them, all but one of them makes a fermion, so this is the only case we need to consider). In particular write$$b_1=f_3f_4,\,b_2=f_5f_6\implies[b_1,\,b_2]=f_3\{f_4,\,f_5\}f_6-\{f_3,\,f_5\}f_4f_6+f_5f_3\{f_4,\,f_6\}-f_5\{f_3,\,f_6\}f_4$$in analogy with 9 [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Commutator#Additional_identities). If the anticommutators vanish at spacelike separations, so does $[b_1,\,b_2]$.

Comment: Could you please point me to a link where  the  $\{\eta_i,\,\eta_j\}=[\eta_i,\,c_j]=0$ is derived?

Comment: Is it still true that the $\left[\psi_\xi(x) , \overline\psi_\eta(y)\right]$ in the question does not vanish for spacelike separations and so we need to postulate superselection rules?

Comment: Ok, I think I've found a couple of references: [Fermionic Algebra and Fock Space](http://bolvan.ph.utexas.edu/~vadim/Classes/2011f/ffs.pdf) and [Supersymmetry, see par 4.3.2 etc...](https://physik.uni-graz.at/~axm/susy2016-17.pdf).

Answer (score 0):

I understand that we have to use **canonical anticommutation relations** to satisfy micro-causality in this case.
For example from [Tong's lectures](http://www.damtp.cam.ac.uk/user/tong/qft/five.pdf) about "*Quantizing the Dirac Field*" we see that in case of fermions

$\left\{ \psi_\alpha(x) , \psi_\beta(y) \right\} = 0$ for $(x-y)^2<0$

> The theory remains causal as long as fermionic operators are not observable. If you think this is a little weak, remember that no one has ever seen a physical measuring apparatus come back to minus itself when you rotate by 360 degrees!

Thus this is also related to another [answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/54609/157886) which explains that

> Only products that are Grassmann-even – contain an even number of
>   fermionic factors – are measurable due to the existence of
>   superselection sectors.

So the "*problem*" is "*solved*" by noting that - as the [wiki page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermionic_field#Dirac_fields) puts it:

> Since all reasonable observables (such as energy, charge, particle number, etc.) are built out of an **even** number of fermion fields, the commutation relation vanishes between any two observables at spacetime points outside the light cone

Comment: If you write fermions $f_1,\,f_2$ as $f_i=\eta_ic_i$ for Grassmann numbers $\eta_i$ commuting with the $c_j$, $\{f_1,\,f_2\}=\eta_1\eta_2[c_1,\,c_2]$.

Comment: @J.G. In my understanding you refer to the creation operators, about which I've found a related answer, but I've also noticed this [comment](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/141099/grassmann-number-representation-for-fermions#comment294307_142308) there: "*still Grassmann variables remain Grassmann variables, which are not any kind of operators and can't be reduced to a set of real numbers!*"

Comment: When we move from the classical theory in which bosons commute and fermions anticommute to a quantized one in which CCRs and CARs are nonzero, everything becomes an operator with complex matrix elements, including the $\eta_i$. (They'll be infinite-dimensional because of the $x$-dependence, *contra* the example to which the linked comment alluded.) But they'll still commute with the $c_j$. The calculation is then as before.

Comment: @J.G. it would be great if you could write a bit more detailed answer (more expanded than these interesting but very succinct comments) that I'd be happy to accept (and study more in depth)